# Handle special character in xml parsing

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am facing a problem while parsing the XML file. Actually one of element tag in the XML file contains a special character which is &

```
<organization>AT&T</organization>
```

and for parsing this xml file i am using-

```
 XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
```

and when my xml file goes for parsing i am getting following exception-
' ' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 43, position 15.

How to handle it so that i could have my original data i.e AT&T and also i bypass this exception. Any link or help would be highly appropriated.

Comment: Then you have invalid XML files. Step 1 is to insist that whatever generates those files gets fixed to avoid spreading the sickness. As a workaround, try the links above and look for a preprocessing solution.

Comment: I fixed it by replacing all the invalid special chars in the text file and then create the valid xml file. Is it good idea or there is any best idea?

Comment: @SunilSingh: XML parsers expect a valid XML file, if you don't have a valid XML file, then you need to do preprocessing to get a valid file first. So yes, that is probably the best solution.